# Is it possible to use registration free activation of an ActiveX compoment loaded by IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, registration

I have written a .NET control that wraps an ActiveX component. The ActiveX component has been provided to me by a third party. The .NET control is registered for COM Interop, and is invoked by our users via an  tag in Internet Explorer. Right now, in order to get everything to work, I have to use regsvr32 against the ActiveX component. Is there a way that I can use registration free activation instead?

From my brief research, it looks like it might not be possible. I think I would need to include a manifest for iexplore.exe, which I'm not allowed to do. If anyone has experience using registration free activation of ActiveX components that are loaded by IE, I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm afraid you need to register the ActiveX control first.